# Changing directory in Ansys Fluent Solution to a folder with a white space in its name by using the console

Tags: console, ansys

I am using Ansys Fluent Solution 2021 R1, and I would like to change directory in the console to a folder that has a white space in its name, such as "a folder". For that purpose I am using the `chdir` command and making different attempts, namely

```
chdir a folder
chdir "a folder"
chdir a\ folder
chdir a/ folder
chdir "a/ folder"
chdir "a\ folder"
```

but none of them is working. Do you know how such command should be written?

Comment: I think it is way easier to have directories with '_' and '-' instead of white spaces, you cannot change de name instead ?

Comment: @coyote Yes, I can. I am doing that now. But almost every good console language has a way of expressing white spaces. Maybe, Fluent also has one ...

Comment: I have found fluent console hard to use (when compared to terminal in debian systems). One way to get around these limitations is using LIPS-scheme, but I do not like the language. If you are fluent, you can do lots of stuff nevertheless.